# how to call onUpdate() in AppWidgetProvider?

Tags: android, widget, timertask

this is my code...

```
String[] show = new String[2];
RemoteViews remoteViews;
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE = "ConfigureWidget";
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionReceiverWidget";   

@Override
public void onUpdate( Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds )
{
    show = getString();

    remoteViews = new RemoteViews( context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget );
    remoteViews.setTextViewText( R.id.widget_title, show[0]);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText( R.id.widget_textview, show[1]);

    Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, SuitAuto.class);
    configIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE);

    Intent active = new Intent(context, WordWidget.class);
    active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
    active.putExtra("msg", "Message for Button 1");

    PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
    PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.update, actionPendingIntent);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Lilo, configPendingIntent);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews );
}

private String[] getString() {
    String[] hon = new String[2];
    KamusWidget ad = new KamusWidget(null);
    ad.open();
    hon = ad.getwordday();
    ad.close();
    return hon;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // v1.5 fix that doesn't call onDelete Action
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)) {
        final int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

        if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
            this.onDeleted(context, new int[] { appWidgetId });
        }
    } else {
        // check, if our Action was called
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) {
            String msg = "null";
            try {
                msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.e("Error", "msg = null");
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } else {
            // do nothing
        }

        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}

 }
```

i just want to update widget_title and widget_textview when R.id.update is clicked
it should run function getString to fetch string from other class so that, the new string can be pass to the textview...

any idea?

Answer (score 4):

In the end of the `onReceive` function you should be able to just create a RemoteView and update the widget:

```
ComponentName name = new ComponentName(context, WordWidget.class);
int[] ids = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(name);
if(ids != null && ids.length > 0){
RemoteView remoteViews = new RemoteViews( context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget );
remoteViews.setTextViewText( R.id.widget_title, context.getString(R.id.new_widget_title));
remoteViews.setTextViewText( R.id.widget_textview, context.getString(R.id.new_widget_text));

Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, SuitAuto.class);
configIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE);

Intent active = new Intent(context, WordWidget.class);
active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
active.putExtra("msg", "Message for Button 1");

PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);

remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.update, actionPendingIntent);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Lilo, configPendingIntent);

appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(ids, remoteViews );
}
```

I believe you will need to also set the Intents: if you do not do that the buttons will no longer work once you update the RemoteView.

Comment: it's not clear how we get the appWidgetManager "variable" in your example, I am running into a similar problem, I update the textview through a remoteview, however it doesn't seem to actually change the text.

Comment: If you have a context (any context, such as an Activity or a Service) you should be able to do `AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);`: I use this from inside a Service to update a widget that displays the value of a Bluetooth sensor.

Comment: I've been reading through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220757/android-widget-onclick-listener-for-several-buttons and trying to get it to work for a couple of days.  Finally I found this answer with the AppWidgetManager comment above and I was able to finally get it work.  Upvote!

Answer (score 0):

I believe

```
Intent active = new Intent(context, WordWidget.class);
active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
```

Should be

```
Intent active = new Intent(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
```

Broadcast PendingIntents do not work if their intent was not instantiated with a simple string. setAction() does not do the same thing for some reason.