# How to set onClickListener on button inside Widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have tried to do according to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23221007/2255924). But it is somehow not working.
No errors, which may give clue how to solve.

Inside my manifest, I have this receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".ImageReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/widget_image" />
</receiver>
```

widget_image.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="72dp"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout">
</appwidget-provider>
```

widget_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/bRefresh" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ImageReceiver looks like this:

```
public class ImageReceiver extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static final String REFRESH_BUTTON_CLICKED = "REFRESH_BUTTON_CLICKED";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bRefresh, getPendingSelfIntent(context, REFRESH_BUTTON_CLICKED));
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        if (REFRESH_BUTTON_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Button click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
        intent.setAction(action);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    }
}
```

When I click Button bRefresh, it should show Toast "Button click" but it is not showing. How to solve this problem?

Comment: try return `PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);`

Comment: @MD, no effect. What else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

inside your on update take,

```
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_retry, getPendingSelfIntent(context, MyOnClick));
```

than take,

```
    private static final String MyOnClick = "myOnClickTag";

    protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action)
    {
        // if we brodcast than definetly we have to define ONRECEIVE
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
        intent.setAction(action);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    }
```

and,

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

            if (MyOnClick.equals(intent.getAction()))
            {
                //your onClick action is here

            }
}
```

above code working for me!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your create your own action, you have to register it in your AndroidManifest.xml file. So add this line in the receiver -> intent-filter of your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<receiver android:name=".ImageReceiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    <action android:name="REFRESH_BUTTON_CLICKED"/> // Add this Line
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
    android:resource="@xml/widget_image" />
</receiver>
```