# How execute certain function on clicking on the widget?

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, android-appwidget

I want to change a boolean variable value and the background of the widget on clicking it ?
here is the the widget xml file

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f15"
android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin"
android:id="@+id/appwidget_layout">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/appwidget_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/appwidget_button"/>
```

and here is the widget java acticity

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.example_app_widget_provider);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExampleAppWidgetProvider.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);


        PendingIntent buttonPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appwidget_button, buttonPendingIntent);


        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

public boolean buttonState = false;

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.example_app_widget_provider);

    if (intent.getAction()!= null) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (buttonState) {
            buttonState = false;
            views.setInt(R.id.appwidget_layout, "setBackgroundColor", Color.GREEN);
            views.setInt(R.id.appwidget_text, "setBackgroundColor", Color.GREEN);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            buttonState = true;
            views.setInt(R.id.appwidget_layout, "setBackgroundColor", Color.RED);
            views.setInt(R.id.appwidget_text, "setBackgroundColor", Color.RED);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, ExampleAppWidgetProvider.class),
                views);
    }
}
```

}

when the code runs, the part in the onRecieve method is not executed. I want to know how to receive the click from the same widget that sent the intent, so that I can modify it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

On top of your `Widget` class, create a static variable, which will be your `onClick`:

```
private static final String MyOnClick = "myOnClickTag";
```

Define a helper method to automate the creation of each `PendingIntent`:

```
protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
    intent.setAction(action);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
}
```

Set this `onClick` tag to your view as below:

```
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, 
getPendingSelfIntent(context, MyOnClick));
```

create an `onReceive`method in your `Widget` class and set this `onClick` event inside it:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (MyOnClick.equals(intent.getAction())){

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if (buttonState) {
        buttonState = false;
        views.setInt(R.id.appwidget_layout, "setBackgroundColor", Color.GREEN);
        views.setInt(R.id.appwidget_text, "setBackgroundColor", Color.GREEN);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        buttonState = true;
        views.setInt(R.id.appwidget_layout, "setBackgroundColor", Color.RED);
        views.setInt(R.id.appwidget_text, "setBackgroundColor", Color.RED);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, ExampleAppWidgetProvider.class),
            views);
    }
};
```

Whenever the view that you set the tag is pressed, `onReceive` will capture that and will do the action just the same as our everyday, standard `onClick` event

As for your `onUpdate`:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)    
{
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_det);
    thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);    
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button_stayarm, getPendingSelfIntent(context, MyOnClick1));
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button_awayarm, getPendingSelfIntent(context, MyOnClick2));
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button_dissarm, getPendingSelfIntent(context, MyOnClick3));
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview_gpscoords, "gps cords");
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but it did not work for me. I will try your code in a new new project, may there is something wrong in my app.

Comment: I made a new project with this code, but unfortunately it did not work too.

Comment: I added a toast message in the onUpdate method, and the toast did not appear. which means that the method was not even called.

Comment: Original answer by Canova here (shame on you for stealing without giving credit PartTimeNerd): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220757/android-widget-onclick-listener-for-several-buttons/23221007#23221007. Read my comment on the original answer, this approach doesn't work on all scenarios.