# Providing click method to widgets

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, widget, click, appwidgetprovider

I tried to create a widget and I succeeded, but how can I meet the click needs of the tools in the widget?

What I'm talking about is not redirecting onto an activity, I'm looking for a method where I can create a function.

The layout file used for the widget below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/kare"
    android:theme = "@style/Theme.Mytwo.AppWidgetContainer" >

    <Button
        android:id = "@+id/appwidget_text"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent = "true"
        android:background = "#048018"
        android:text = "clean"
        android:textSize = "24sp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textStyle = "bold" />

</RelativeLayout >
```

This is my widget provider class

```
class NewAppWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {

    override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetIds: IntArray) { // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
        }
    }
}

internal fun updateAppWidget(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetId: Int) {

    val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.new_app_widget )

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
}
```

And finally my provider info file

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description = "@string/app_widget_description"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout = "@layout/new_app_widget"
    android:initialLayout = "@layout/new_app_widget"
    android:minWidth = "100dp"
    android:minHeight = "40dp"
    android:previewImage = "@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
    android:previewLayout = "@layout/new_app_widget"
    android:resizeMode = "horizontal|vertical"
    android:targetCellWidth = "2"
    android:targetCellHeight = "2"
    android:updatePeriodMillis = "86400000"
    android:widgetCategory = "home_screen" />
```

Comment: SEE THIS LINK https://stackoverflow.com/a/23221007/12272687

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "create a function". The only way to get something to happen when a widget is clicked is via `RemoteViews#setOnCheckedChangeResponse` or `RemoteViews#setOnClickFillInIntent` or
`RemoteViews#setOnClickPendingIntent` or
`RemoteViews#setOnClickResponse`.
Apart from calling `RemoteViews.RemoteResponse#addSharedElement`,
all that any of these can do is to send out an `Intent`, which can start an `Activity` or awaken a `BroadcastReceiver`.

You can't execute your own code inside the widget: any code that you want to execute in response to a click on a widget has to be in the `Activity` or the `BroadcastReceiver`. It doesn't have to be an `Activity` or a `BroadcastReceiver` inside the app that created the widget, although it usually will be.

Since the `RemoteViews` is created inside your app's `AppWidgetProvider#updateAppWidget`, you can put the `appWidgetId` as an extra into the `PendingIntent`, so you can tell which widget was clicked.